# How do I loop through columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, data-cleaning, dplyr

I am trying to clean up my code for cleaning missing data. I have a dataset with 6 columns and the code works if I were to do them individually like this:

```
mammographic_masses <- mammographic_masses %>%
  mutate(birad = replace(birad, birad== "na", NA)) %>%
  mutate(birad = replace(birad, birad== "N/A", NA))
```

But when I try to do it in a for loop like this:

```
for (i in ncol(mammographic_masses)){
  print(class(mammographic_masses[[i]]))
  mammographic_masses <- mammographic_masses %>%
    mutate(mammographic_masses[[,i]] = replace(mammographic_masses[[,i]], mammographic_masses[[,i]] == "na", NA)) %>%
    mutate(mammographic_masses[[,i]] = replace(mammographic_masses[[,i]], mammographic_masses[[,i]] == "N/A", NA))
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  mammographic_masses <- mammographic_masses %>%
    mutate(mammographic_masses[[,i]] ="
>     mutate(mammographic_masses[[,i]] = replace(mammographic_masses[[,i]], mammographic_masses[[,i]] == "N/A", NA))
Error: unexpected '=' in "    mutate(mammographic_masses[[,i]] ="
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I also was reading up on other ways such as apply etc. but i cant figure a way to loop it per column

Comment: `for (i in 1:ncol(.))`. would be a first step, like it is you are only iterating over the last column.

Comment: You may be interested in `mutate_all` (or, if you've already upgraded to the just-released dplyr 1.0, `across()`)

Comment: Another issue is that you're mixing index methods - single brackets with a comma `df[, i]` will give you a 1-column tibble if the input is a tibble, or a single column vector if the input is a data frame. You're wise to use `[[` to guarantee you get a single column vector no matter the input, but don't use `,` inside `[[`, just use `[[i]]`.

Comment: I have another question slightly related. If I have to use value specific to each column, then mutate_all would not work. In this scenario, what can I do?

Comment: @GregorThomas I have tried [[i]] as well but the same error occured. mutate_all works for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, use `mutate_all`.

```
library(dplyr)

mammographic_masses %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) {is.na(x) <- x %in% c("na", "N/A"); x})
#     V1   V2   V3   V4
#1     d    b <NA>    c
#2     d    b <NA> <NA>
#3  <NA> <NA>    d    b
#4     a <NA> <NA>    b
#5     a    b    d <NA>
#6     d    c    b    c
#7     b    b    d <NA>
#8  <NA> <NA> <NA>    d
#9     a    d    d <NA>
#10 <NA>    b    d <NA>
```

**Test data creation code**

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 10
mammographic_masses <- replicate(4, sample(c(letters[1:4], "na", "N/A"), n, TRUE))
mammographic_masses <- as.data.frame(mammographic_masses)
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have looked at the different mutate functions! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To provide the "new" `dplyr` preferred `across` as well as `str_replace_all` (good point @Gregor)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


mammographic_masses %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), 
         ~ str_replace_all(., c("na" = NA_character_, "N/A" = NA_character_))))

#>      V1   V2   V3   V4
#> 1     d    b <NA>    c
#> 2     d    b <NA> <NA>
#> 3  <NA> <NA>    d    b
#> 4     a <NA> <NA>    b
#> 5     a    b    d <NA>
#> 6     d    c    b    c
#> 7     b    b    d <NA>
#> 8  <NA> <NA> <NA>    d
#> 9     a    d    d <NA>
#> 10 <NA>    b    d <NA>
```

Same data as Rui

```r
set.seed(2020)
n <- 10
mammographic_masses <- replicate(4, sample(c(letters[1:4], "na", "N/A"), n, TRUE))
mammographic_masses <- as.data.frame(mammographic_masses)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
mammographic_masses %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(na_if(., "na"), "N/A")))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 10
mammographic_masses <- replicate(4, sample(c(letters[1:4], "na", "N/A"), n, TRUE))
mammographic_masses <- as.data.frame(mammographic_masses)
```